# My Neural Network is not learning anything

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I try to train convolutional neural net for a classification problem. However, my neural net is not learning anything. It guesses only two labels and ignores the rest. Even though I try to train to overfit my neural net, the loss function is not decreasing at all. My I try to make my network go as deep as 12 layers of the convolutional neural net in order to overfit the subsampling data. However, it is not working. Do you have any suggestion what to look?

Comment: Could you please provide the distribution in terms of proportion, of the target categorical variable: Could it be because that the target classes are imbalanced?

Comment: Does it need to be balanced if I want to overfit it? Those two labels were contributed more than 50 percent of the total label in the training data.

Comment: Add more details to your question along with the snippet of your code

Comment: There are lots of ways that a neural network can go wrong. To get anything more than a guess on what the problem is, you will need to show some of your data preparation, training and testing code, plus explain your data and show a few samples.

Comment: Start with your loss function, then confirm your Xs and labels are in the correct order, then post some code here

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that while training, you are passing the data in a random order. It looks like you are passing all images of one class at a time then the next class etc. Shuffle the images and pass it in a random manner.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bazillion things that can go wrong when training a DNN, and it's often helpful to heavily simplify your starter net/data before you move onto your actual problem.

Without any more information on the specifics of your setup, etc, the first thing I would recommend for you to try is to overfit your net to random noise. Don't make it deep just yet! You want to make sure that everything else if your setup is kosher first.

So: Create a random-noise data set with labels, OR extract a small (< 50) or so images for you to use as your dev set, and try to overfit on those in the very beginning, with a vastly simplified net. This should always be your first step.

Answer (score 0):

There might be many reasons behind such behavior of your model. But, I am listing out some of them which I have found out from my experience.

Make sure your data don't contain any missing values. If you are training your model with Keras then it doesn't throw an error message in case of missing values (nan values). Check all the input values carefully before feeding it to network.

Secondly, I would suggest try to change learning rate and check if your accuracy is increasing or not.

In some cases, while processing our data, nan values are generated in some features which causes such problems.